# Is Parallel.ForEach obsolete. old, out of fashion?

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, parallel-processing, async-await, .net-4.5

Good day,

Parallel execution can be achieved through multiple ways. From strictly manual "multithreading" to using various "helpers" created by Microsoft. One of those helpers is the Parallel class.

One of my colleagues is insisting that **Parallel.ForEach** (or Parallel class overall) is "old" and shouldn't be used. Instead, he says, one should use async operations. In other words you should use `Task.WhenAll()` instead of `Parallel.ForEach()` .

When asked why not use `Parallel.ForEach(),` when this is exactly what was needed - **multiple expensive operations executed in parallel**, he replied that `Parallel.ForEach()` is old and that Microsoft recommends using async/await wherever possible.

I searched all over MSDN and Stackoverflow and everywhere I could but I couldn't find anything pointing at the necessity of using async/await instead of .Parallel. While you often can achieve similar results by interchanging these  tools it doesn't mean that **Parallel.ForEach** is obsolete. Or does it?

Anyone has a link to some "best practices" or "recommendations" by a reputable body (MSDN?) that would say that `Parallel.ForEach()` is being phased out and one needs to stick with creating, running and awaiting tasks?

Please do not post answers related to **Parallel VS Async** for this as this is not the question.

**The question is:** Since you can make tasks run in parallel using async/await `WhenAll` (`WaitAll` etc.), does it make 'Parallel' class obsolete, old, or not fashionable in .NET 4.5 onward?

Comment: If he's claiming that "Microsoft recommends" then he should be able to show that recommendation. I haven't seen such a thing myself.

Comment: Your friend is confusing parallelism with asynchrony.

Comment: @JonSkeet you see I do not want to ask him for proof before I actually do my research for I do not want to appear hostile. What if your (or some one  else's) answere were like "sure, everyone knows it's obsolete - we keep it there only for older folks"?

Comment: @AlexeiFimine: I think you can ask in a non-hostile way, and it's entirely reasonable to do so.

Comment: @JonSkeet Eventually I will ask. Now with your help I am preparing for the conversation. It's always better to be prepared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think `Parallel.ForEach` is obsolete.

Ever since introducing the Task Parallel Library (TPL) with .NET 4, Microsoft has [distinguished between "Data Parallelism" (e.g. `Parallel.ForEach`) and "Task Parallelism" (`Task`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). From MSDN:

> - *"Data parallelism refers to scenarios in which the same operation is performed concurrently (that is, **in parallel**) on elements in a source collection or array."*
> - *"[T]ask parallelism refers to one or more independent tasks running **concurrently**."*

<sup>(Emphasis by me. Like [dcastro commented (above)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919727/is-parallel-foreach-obsolete-old-out-of-fashion#comment47960878_29919727): *"Your friend is confusing parallelism with asynchrony."*)</sup>

These two types of parallelism/concurrency pursue different goals, so the TPL offers different capabilities for each of them.

Conceptually, `Task.WhenAll` belongs into the task parallelism category, so I don't think it obsolesces something that belongs to the other (data parallelism) category.

Comment: Thank you. 

In my case I invoke mutiple external calls to different sources. Those calls are completely independend of each other. However I cannot proceed before all of them are done. Both Parallel.ForEach and Task.WhenAll work fine here. However, i find that ParallelForEach is more elegant and involves less code. His take is that yes, perhaps it's not necessarily wrong to use it but the preferred method is Task.WhenAll() .

Comment: @AlexeiFimine: Some general advice about differences of opinion: Ask your colleague *why* he claims that `Task.WhenAll` is preferred. While there is often no clear-cut right and wrong in such cases, people should be able to rationally back up their claims. (See [Jon Skeet's comment above.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919727/29919803#comment47960546_29919727)) If his arguments convince you (i.e. they are "better" than your current opinion), change your code. If you think that you have the better argument ("more elegant code with Parallel.ForEach"), stay with your version of the code.

Answer (score 2):

`Parallel.ForEach` (and PLINQ as a whole) has abilities that are not available in the `async` language support.

For example, you can limit the degree of parallelism (eg. 100 items to process, but do no more that 10 at a time). Thus it is not obsolete.

Fundamentally `async` is about making concurrent operations – without any assumptions of threading – easier to write. PLINQ is about computation making use of many cores.

I suspect your colleague is reading too much into direct use of Task Parallel Library (TPL) largely being unnecessary with `async` in the language (except for the return type of `async` functions). But PLINQ was always a different layer over TPL. If anything PLINQ and `async` are two separate ways to make use of TPL for different purposes.

Comment: Good one with the DegreeOfParallelism. I have always found it useful in the way it's implemented. I would sometimes even use it for testing and debugging like in #If Debug .DegreeOfParallelism = 1

Answer (score 2):

`async` and `await` have nothing at all to do with parallelism. They are technologies used to make existing asynchronous APIs easier to consume and expose. `async` and `await` do not initiate parallelism or concurrency. In fact **`await` ends parallelism by waiting for something that is already running**.

`Parallel.ForEach` is used to process a set of homogeneous items in the same way on multiple cores. You can simulate `Parallel.ForEach` by spawning a big number of tasks. There is no advantage in doing that. In fact it introduces inefficiencies and obfuscates the code. It is possible and works but it is an inferior way of doing things if `Parallel.ForEach` is applicable.

I think your colleague does not understand that await really just waits. It does not start something.

Use Parallel.* and PLINQ (mostly) for CPU-bound work.

Comment: await Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task> Tasks) will actually launch all of the tasks in the Tasks collection in parallel and then wait for all of them to complete. This design does exactly what ParallelForEach would do. 

However, in order to achieve that I'd need to create a list of those tasks manually. There is also the problem of "getting out of the async".  It looks a lot more intuitive and clean to use Parallel.ForEach in my case.

Comment: @AlexeiFimine **No!** It will do what the name says. It waits. The tasks must already be running.; But your conclusion is right: Why manage tasks for CPU bound work when you can just use Parallel.

Comment: @AlexeiFimine Those tasks were *probably*, but not necessarily, started when they were first created. `Task.WhenAll` doesn't start them, and `await` doesn't either, as usr pointed out. There is absolutely no guarantee that those tasks will be processed in parallel, nor that they'll actually be asynchronous - for all we know, they could be executed synchronously and sequentially. Again, all `await` does is wait.

Comment: @dcastro  Thanks for your replies. Wouldn't 
await Task.WhenAll(mytasks) launch the tasks in parallel and wait for all of them to finish? You say "probably". What does it mean? Do I need to manually "start" them? In my case they work fine without it and the performance is just as with Parallel.Foreach so they sure are running in parallel.

Comment: @AlexeiFimine Again, `await Task.WhenAll` doesn't launch anything. I said "probably", and not definitely, because *most* APIs return tasks that have already been started, such as `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync` or `HttpClient.PostAsync`. But if I created a new task and awaited it without starting it, e.g. `await new Task()`, the method would never continue. But that's beside the point - the point is, awaiting tasks doesn't *meeaan* they'll run in parallel, even though they might.

Comment: @AlexeiFimine you stated two times now that you think WhenAll launches tasks. This is in contradiction to what I said. Don't just make a claim. Explain why you think this would be the case so that we can have a discussion about it. I'm telling you: WhenAll does not launch tasks. It waits. Very simple. The name says exactly that.

Comment: @usr I don't "think" that WhenAll() launches tasks - I just observed that behavior. You're telling me that WhenAll does not launch tasks, but I see them launching and executing. I don't know if it is "supposed" to launch them but I know that I don't have no Run() or Start() in my code. Yet tasks get executed just after the await Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task> Tasks)  line.

Comment: The tasks were already running. Most tasks are already running when you obtain them. Unstarted tasks are an anti-pattern (and a design bug in the framework in my mind),

Comment: @usr Yeah. I misinterpreted my own code :) You're right tasks were running. I called them in the previous line.